# Getopt Not Finding '*' Flag when trying to use

Tags: c, getopt

I am trying to use getopt to get the '*' character when I am doing

```
 ls \*
```

or

```
 ls \*.c
```

I am using this for my own `ls` command that I am trying to add the support for globbing. Below is the code that I am trying to use the getopt command for.

```
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "*laFi1i")) != -1) {
    switch (c) {
        case 'l' : L = 1; break; 
        case 'a' : A = 1; break;
        case 'F' : F = 1; break;
        case 'i' : I = 1; break;
        case '1' : ONE = 1; break;
        case '*' : GLOB = 1; break;
    }
}
```

Why is it that when i try to use the switch cases nothing is being found?

thank you

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but I think you are using the wrong tool here. `getopt` is for option parsing. Options are: `-r`, `-l`, `--all`, `-f file`. Whereas just `"*.c"` is not really an option, but more of a file argument. What I'd do (if you really want to use getopt) set `opterr = 0` and getopt until it returns `'?'`. Then implement your globbing logic for the remaining arguments. Or implement: `-f *.c`.

Comment: Why would you want to add support for globbing in ls?